# How to find index of a control in a placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexof, asp.net-placeholder

I have the following code :

```
   Label docsLabel = new Label();
   docsLabel = (Label)tasksPlaceholder.FindControl("taskdocs_" + taskId);
   int index = tasksPlaceholder.Controls.IndexOf(docsLabel);
```

The label is found within the placeholder, but when I call .IndexOf() it always returns -1.

How do I find the correct position of this control?

Comment: Why do you use `new Label()` at all when you use `FindControl` one line later anyway? This is just confusing and does nothing.

Comment: Probably because the label is not a direct child of the placeholder.

Comment: Does the `(Label)tasksPlaceholder.FindControl("taskdocs_" + taskId);` really find the control? Don't you passing null to `IndexOf()`?

Comment: It does find the control, but its not a direct child of the placeholder.

Comment: @AndreJ, then you cannot expect it to be in the placeholder's controls collection.

Comment: Well then its just silly that .FindControl() can find it but cannot be found with .indexOf(). Thanks anyways, will make a plan

Comment: Is this really the original code or is it simplified?

Comment: Just a thought, if indexof is not working then you can loop through the controls collection of the placeholder and check for reference equality. Simultaneously you can set a counter and increase it by 1 as you keep on checking. Not very sure if this will give you the correct index though.

Comment: Its the original code, the element I want to update is 3 levels down (TableRow -> TableCell ->Label

Comment: Thanks @samar, will give it a try. I just want to update the text of the control, seems like its not easy to do if its in a placeholder

Comment: Another way could be writing a recursive function to check for child controls within a control but then you would need to be careful about the counter as it might increment unnecessarily on recursion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an important information in your comments:

> the element I want to update is 3 levels down (TableRow -> TableCell ->Label)

[`Control.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) finds all control in this [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whereas [`ControlCollection.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.indexof%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) finds only controls in this control. So if this control contains for example a table which contains rows and cells and every cell contains also controls, all of these controls will not be found by `IndexOf`, only the top-control is searched.

`Control.FindControl` will search all controls that belong to this `NamingContainer`(a control that implements `INamingContainer`). A table/row/cell does not implement it, that's why all of these controls are also searched with `FindControl`.

However, `FindControl` will not search through sub-`NamingContainers` (like a `GridView` in a `GridViewRow`).

This reproduces your  issue:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TableRow -> TableCell ->Label
    var table = new Table();
    var row = new TableRow();
    var cell = new TableCell();
    var label = new Label();
    label.ID = "taskdocs_1";
    cell.Controls.Add(label);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    tasksPlaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label docsLabel = (Label)tasksPlaceholder.FindControl("taskdocs_1");
    int index = tasksPlaceholder.Controls.IndexOf(docsLabel); 
    // docsLabel != null and index = -1 --> quod erat demonstrandum
}
```

---

> How do I find the correct position of this control?

If you want to find the row-number this label belongs to:

```
Label docsLabel = (Label)tasksPlaceholder.FindControl("taskdocs_1");
TableRow row = (TableRow)docsLabel.Parent;
Table table = (Table)row.Parent;
int rowNumber = table.Rows.GetRowIndex(row);
```